# Ethereum web3js method call fail

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I have a simple solidity smart contract with method like:

```
function foo(uint a) public {
    b =  bytes32(1);
        emit Event(a, b);
        emit Event2(a, b);
    }
```

(full code is here: https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1.js)

and invoke it using web3.js code :

```
contract = testContract.at('xxxAddress')   

// contract.foo(6); // Failed, Why?

//Success
contract.foo.sendTransaction(6, {from: eth.accounts[1]},function(error, result) {
            console.log("Got err:", error, ", result: ", result) 
    }
);
```

but, why straightforward contract.foo(6) failed? Can any expert explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to a function that modifies the blockchain needs to send as a transaction since it requires gas to run. This is why you need to send a transaction and not just call the function. You can find more about it [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send).